# Replace string only if all characters match (Thai)

Tags: python-3.x, string, thai

The problem is that มาก technically is in มาก็. Because มาก็ is มาก +  ็.

So when I do

```
"แชมพูมาก็เยอะ".replace("มาก", " X ")
```

I end up with

```
แชมพู X  ็เยอะ
```

And what I want

```
แชมพู X เยอะ
```

What I really want is to force the last character ก็ to count as a single character, so that มาก no longer matches มาก็.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't found a proper solution, I was able to find *a* solution. I split each string into separate (combined) characters via regex. Then I compare those lists to each other.

```
# Check is list is inside other list
def is_slice_in_list(s,l):
    len_s = len(s) #so we don't recompute length of s on every iteration
    return any(s == l[i:len_s+i] for i in range(len(l) - len_s+1))

def is_word_in_string(w, s):
    a = regex.findall(u'\X', w)
    b = regex.findall(u'\X', s)
    return is_slice_in_list(a, b)

assert is_word_in_string("มาก็", "พูมาก็เยอะ") == True
assert is_word_in_string("มาก", "พูมาก็เยอะ") == False
```

The regex will split like this:

```
พู ม า ก็ เ ย อ ะ
ม า ก
```

And as it compares ก็ to ก the function figures the words are not the same.

I will mark as answered but if there is a nice or "proper" solution I will chose that one.